# Google Form - Delete rows/records older than 3 years

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-workspace

I have a google form that records sales of certain items to customers. I need to automatically delete rows that are older than 3 years. This is for GDPR data retention reasons.

I though I could have a trigger than runs nightly to run the script but I am unsure how to code this.

The timestamp currently sits in row A.

I am assuming that deleting the data from the spreadsheet will also delete the record of it on the form.

Comment: Removing responses in the linked sheet does not remove responses stored in the form

Comment: Just to be 100% clear about this: `I am assuming that deleting the data from the spreadsheet will also delete the record of it on the form.` **This is a common BUT incorrect assumption** As @Cooper comments, `Removing responses in the linked sheet does not remove responses stored in the form`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this task, you can use Google Apps Script to create a time-driven trigger that runs nightly and deletes rows older than 3 years from your Google Sheet. Here's an example script to get you started:

1. Open your Google Sheet.
2. Click on "Extensions" > "Apps Script."
3. Replace any existing code in the script editor with the following code:

   ```
    function deleteOldRows() {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
       var currentDate = new Date();
       var threeYearsAgo = new Date(currentDate);
       threeYearsAgo.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() - 3);

       var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
       var rowsToDelete = [];

       for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Assuming the timestamp is in column A, starting from the second row
          var timestamp = new Date(data[i][0]);
          if (timestamp < threeYearsAgo) {
          rowsToDelete.push(i + 1); // Adding 1 to convert to sheet index (1-based)
          }
       }

    // Delete rows in reverse order to avoid shifting issues
       for (var j = rowsToDelete.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
          sheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[j]);
       }
   }

   // Trigger to run the deleteOldRows function nightly
   function createTrigger() {
      // Adjust the time zone to your preference
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('deleteOldRows')
        .timeBased()
        .everyDays(1) // Run every day
        .create();
    }
   ```
4. Save the script (File > Save).
5. You can run the createTrigger function manually the first time to set up the trigger. After running it once, you can close the script editor.

Now, the deleteOldRows function will run every night and delete rows older than 3 years from your sheet. Make sure to test the script on a copy of your data first to avoid accidental data loss.

Remember that deleting rows from the sheet will also delete the corresponding records on the form, as they are linked to the rows in the sheet.

Comment: `deleting rows from the sheet will also delete the corresponding records on the form, as they are linked to the rows in the sheet.` This is not correct. **All** responses are maintained _in the Form_. Any deletions from a linked spreadsheet have no impact whatsoever on the Form. This can be confirmed by unlinking the Form from the Spreadsheet, then re-creating a spreadsheet link (to the same spreadsheet). The new response sheet will contain ALL the submissions including any deleted from the "old" responses sheet.